# Uninstalling python is not unistalling the 'dbt' package

Tags: python, dbt

"dbt" package was installed using the command
`pip install dbt-snowflake`

dbt commands were used successfully (`dbt debug` , `dbt run` etc.)

After that python was completely uninstalled and installed again.
The dbt commands are successfully running without installing them again using pip.
Is it possible that dbt was not uninstalled along with python ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Uninstalling `python` will not remove packages that you pip-installed.

Those are third party packages and not actually part of the python installation at all.

If you want to uninstall those packages, you should use `pip uninstall <package-name>`.